# What does this combination of any, all, and mutliple 'in' in a statement mean?

Tags: python

When I read something like

```
if any(x in str for x in a):
```

how should I break down the meaning of this?

update:
I understand what this does

```
x in str
```

and

```
for x in a
```

but what are they doing together?

Comment: `any` accepts an iterable and returns `True` if any value in the iterable are `True`. `x in str for x in a` is a generator that iterates over `a` and returns the outcome of the expression `x in str` for every `x` in `a`

Comment: It asks if any of the items in `a` are in `str`...

Comment: You should specify what `a` and `str` are. Normally `str` is a method, so unless you're setting it to something else, you're asking if `x` is in the method.

Comment: @Chrispresso well, not a method, but yes, it is a built-in.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this down with an example.

```
a = ['hello', 'taco', 'pizza']
str = 'taco salad'
print([x for x in a]) #['hello', 'taco', 'pizza']
```

Now `any` takes an iterable object and returns `True` if any of the elements within are `True.

```
any([True, False, None])  # True
any([False, None])  # False
```

Combining the examples:

```
any(x in str for x in a)
```

This will check each element in `a` and determine if the string is found in `str`, in this case `'taco salad'`. `'hello'` is not in `'taco salad'` so that is `False`, `'taco'` is contained in `'taco salad'`, so it is `True`. Because one of the values evaluates to `True`, it immediately returns `True` since there is no need to evaluate further.

Answer (score 0):

read `for x in a`: for every element `x` in the iterable `a` collect the boolean value `x in str` - is any of them `True`?

So read in the list expression the right most `for x in <iterable>` - the expression in fron of this is what should be collected.

Comment: What do you mean by "collect the boolean value?" what is exactly the output of "for x in a" when it is not used as a forloop?

Comment: the list expression collects the output of the expression in front of the for loop - into a list. - without a for loop you wouldn't have a list expression.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `any()` is an interable object. The function returns true if any of the elements in the object are true.

`x in str` is true if the value of `x` is a substring of the value of `str` (I'm assuming these are strings -- you can also use `in` with other containers, like searching for an element of a list or testing if a key is in a dictionary).

`for x in a` means it iterates over the elements of the container `a`, with `x` holding each element.

So if `a` is a list of strings, this will tell you if `x` is a substring of any of them.

Comment: So it looks like there are two things going on: x in str and for x in a. how does both of them interact with each other?

Comment: Yes. Those two uses of `in` are mostly unrelated, except that they both apply to collections of things.

Comment: They don't really interact with each other at all. It's no different from `[x + 1 for x in a]`

Comment: The general structure is `<expression using x> for x in a`. It just happens that the expression in your case is `x in str`